# How to create Table of Content in java using Apache POI?

Tags: java, header, docx, tableofcontents

Anyone please give me a simple example. 
i am unable to find example about Table of content using Apache POI Docx.

### Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class App {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  doc.createTOC();
  addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 1", 1);  
  addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 2", 2);  

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();


  CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
  CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
  toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
  toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);

  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
  paragraph.setStyle("heading 1");  


  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
  paragraph.setStyle("heading 2");  


  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\toc.docx");
    doc.write(fos);
 }
 private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, String strStyleId, int headingLevel) {  

     CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();  
     ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);  

     CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();  
     styleName.setVal(strStyleId);  
     ctStyle.setName(styleName);  

     CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();  
     indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));  

     // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar  
     ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);  

     CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();  
     ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);  

     // style shows up in the formats bar  
     ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);  

     // style defines a heading of the given level  
     CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();  
     ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);  
     ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);  

     XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);  

     // is a null op if already defined  
     XWPFStyles styles = docxDocument.createStyles();  

     style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);  
     styles.addStyle(style);  

 }  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot for Table of Content (toc) and found many answers on the internet but all are out date for me I use

`poi-ooxml  5.2.3` 
`poi-ooxml-full 5.2.3` 
`xmlbeans 5.1.1` 
`spark-excel_2.10 0.8.3` 
I am not sure that all these libraries are necessary for code. I just mention this because these packages are in my poi.xml file and my code is working. After you create a document using this code when you open the file the first time it shows pop window just press "yes".

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class toc02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    doc.createTOC();
    addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 1", 1);
    addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "heading 2", 2);

    // the body content
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();

    CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
    CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
    toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
    toc.setDirty(true);

    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("The Body:");

    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
    paragraph.setStyle("heading 1");

    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
    paragraph.setStyle("heading 2");

    paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    run.setText("Lorem ipsum");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\toc.docx");
    doc.write(fos);
}

private static void addCustomHeadingStyle(XWPFDocument docxDocument, String strStyleId, int headingLevel) {

    CTStyle ctStyle = CTStyle.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setStyleId(strStyleId);

    CTString styleName = CTString.Factory.newInstance();
    styleName.setVal(strStyleId);
    ctStyle.setName(styleName);

    CTDecimalNumber indentNumber = CTDecimalNumber.Factory.newInstance();
    indentNumber.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(headingLevel));

    // lower number > style is more prominent in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setUiPriority(indentNumber);

    CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
    ctStyle.setUnhideWhenUsed(onoffnull);

    // style shows up in the formats bar
    ctStyle.setQFormat(onoffnull);

    // style defines a heading of the given level
    CTPPrGeneral ppr = CTPPrGeneral.Factory.newInstance();
    ppr.setOutlineLvl(indentNumber);
    ctStyle.setPPr(ppr);

    XWPFStyle style = new XWPFStyle(ctStyle);

    // is a null op if already defined
    XWPFStyles styles = docxDocument.createStyles();

    style.setType(STStyleType.PARAGRAPH);
    styles.addStyle(style);
}

}
```

I just updates a few fields from the above code.
change from this

```
CTPPr ppr = CTPPr.Factory.newInstance();
```

to this

```
CTPPrGeneral ppr = CTPPrGeneral.Factory.newInstance();
```

change from this

```
toc.setDirty(STOnOff.TRUE);
```

to this

```
 toc.setDirty(true);
```