# How can I add a TOC to my .docx with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I add TOC to my .docx with Apache POI 5.2.3? I'm using Linux and LibreOffice Writer if it is not the same as Microsoft Word for TOC. I tried the code from those questions: [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291213/how-to-create-table-of-content-in-java-using-apache-poi) [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235909/creating-a-table-of-contents-for-a-xwpfdocument-with-page-numbers-indication), but it didn't work.

My code:

```java
addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "Heading 1", 1);
addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "Heading 2", 2);
addCustomHeadingStyle(doc, "Heading 3", 3);

XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
doc.createTOC();
CTP ctP = paragraph.getCTP();
CTSimpleField toc = ctP.addNewFldSimple();
toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");
toc.setDirty(true);
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);

paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
run=paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("The Body:");

paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
run=paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("Heading 1");
paragraph.setStyle("Heading 1");

paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
run=paragraph.createRun();
run.setText("Heading 1");
paragraph.setStyle("Heading 1");

paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
run=paragraph.createRun();
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
run.setText("Heading 2");
paragraph.setStyle("Heading 2");

paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
run = paragraph.createRun();
run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
run.setText("Heading 3");
paragraph.setStyle("Heading 3");
```

`toc.setInstr("TOC \\h");` just adds an empty line with nothing in it and `doc.createTOC();` create the header: "Table of Contents" and not a TOC.

When I put this code at the end of the function, after the creation of the paragraphs, it generates a TOC with "Error: Reference source not found".

```java
CTSdtBlock block = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSdt();
TOC toc = new TOC(block);
for (XWPFParagraph par : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    String parStyle = par.getStyle();
    if (parStyle != null && parStyle.startsWith("Heading ")) {
        try {
            int level = Integer.parseInt(parStyle.substring("Heading ".length()));
            toc.addRow(level, par.getText(), 1, "112723803");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create a TOC that automatically updates when a new paragraph that is header is added to the file? Do I need to set the paragraphs as bookmark?

Comment: try making a docx the way you want it and print it out to see what the structure is.

Comment: when I open the docx there is no TOC

Comment: @K.Nicholas if I check a working document with TOC structure it prints it with all of the content of the TOC already. so it's not helping me to create one, only how it should look like after it updates